# Installing an apk through adb - aborted

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, apk, android-5.0-lollipop

https://github.com/JonWoodlief/android-pololu-maestro-ssc

I'm intending to use this to learn how to manipulate servos connected to a pololu maestro card hooked up to my android via micro-usb to mini-usb cable. I'm running a verizon Galaxy S5 (SM-G900V) and I'm rooted on android 5.0. I'm running Wireless ADB using Konnect-ADB.

when I run

```
adb install C:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\android-pololu-maestro-ssc-master\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
```

I get

```
[100%] /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Aborted
```

Any clue to what the problem is, or what i can do to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `adb install -r C:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\android-pololu-maestro-ssc-master\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk`

Make sure your phone is accepting apps from unknown sources, in developer options.